# check if there are two or more equal values in Json

Tags: java, android, json

How I should process this Json, to extract the **cat1** value once in a Spinner, and in the second Spinner based on the first spinner selection I display **book1** and **book2**.

**Json:**

```
{
 "library":
[
{
   "Cat": "cat1",
   "Book": "book1",
   "authur": "authur1"
 },
 {
   "Cat": "cat1",
   "Book": "book2",
   "authur": "authur2"
 },
 {
   "Cat": "cat2",
   "Book": "book3",
   "authur": "authur3"
 }
]
}
```

Comment: *Step 1)* Use a JSON parser. --- *Step 2)* Group the data by `Cat` --- *Step 3)* Fill spinner1 with categories. --- *Step 4)* On select of spinner1 value, fill spinner2 with books. --- Each step would be a *specific* question, if you have a question about it. You shouldn't because code for all steps can be found on the web. As-is your question is "too broad", and reads like a "write the code for me" request, which is definitely off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a library like Gson or Jackson for creating domain objects (you need to define them before) out of the Json. Afterwards you can easily extract whatever values you like.

This is an example:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Comment: Please,
Can you give me an example link.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Answer (score 0):

Parse your `JSON` data and store it into `ArrayList` and populate it on `Spinner` using `ArrayAdapter`.

**Here is a sample code for parsing your JSON data:**

```
public void parseJson() {
    String response = "{\n" +
            " \"library\":\n" +
            "[\n" +
            "{\n" +
            "   \"Cat\": \"cat1\",\n" +
            "   \"Book\": \"book1\",\n" +
            "   \"authur\": \"authur1\"\n" +
            " },\n" +
            " {\n" +
            "   \"Cat\": \"cat1\",\n" +
            "   \"Book\": \"book2\",\n" +
            "   \"authur\": \"authur2\"\n" +
            " },\n" +
            " {\n" +
            "   \"Cat\": \"cat2\",\n" +
            "   \"Book\": \"book3\",\n" +
            "   \"authur\": \"authur3\"\n" +
            " }\n" +
            "]\n" +
            "}";

    try {
        JSONObject mJsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray libraryJsonArray = mJsonObject.getJSONArray("library");


        ArrayList<String> cats = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> books = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> authors = new ArrayList<>();

        // Get all jsonObject from jsonArray
        for (int i = 0; i < libraryJsonArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = libraryJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            // Cat
            if (jsonObject.has("Cat") && !jsonObject.isNull("Cat")) {
                cats.add(jsonObject.getString("Cat"));
            }

            // Book
            if (jsonObject.has("Book") && !jsonObject.isNull("Book")) {
                books.add(jsonObject.getString("Book"));
            }

            // Author
            if (jsonObject.has("authur") && !jsonObject.isNull("authur")) {
                authors.add(jsonObject.getString("authur"));
            }


            Log.d("SUCCESS", "JSON Object: " + "\nCat: " + cats.get(i)
                    + "\nBook: " + books.get(i) + "\nAuthor: " + authors.get(i));


            // Do something with ArrayList cats, books and authors
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("FAILED", "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
D/SUCCESS: JSON Object: 
           Cat: cat1
           Book: book1
           Author: authur1

D/SUCCESS: JSON Object: 
           Cat: cat1
           Book: book2
           Author: authur2

D/SUCCESS: JSON Object: 
           Cat: cat2
           Book: book3
           Author: authur3
```

Comment: thinks FAT, But the spinner1 it always shows me cat1 in two time .